# Gaussian Mixture Division

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference, bayesian

In Bayesian inference, it is sometimes necessary to divide a Gaussian mixture (GM) posterior distribution by a GM prior. If the posterior GM is given by $$p_{1}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i} \mathcal{N} (x; \mu_{i}, \sigma_{i}), $$ where $\mathcal{N} (\cdot; \mu, \sigma)$ is a Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$, standard deviation $\sigma$, $\alpha_{i} \in [0, 1]$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i} = 1$, and the prior is given by $$ p_{2}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \beta_{i} \mathcal{N}(x; \nu_{i}, \lambda_{i}), $$ where $\beta_{i} \in [0, 1]$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{m} \beta_{i}$ = 1, then how do I approximate $$p_{3} (x) = \frac{p_{1} (x)}{p_{2} (x)} $$
as a GM?

I have attempted to represent both $p_1$ and $p_2$ using their power series and then perform the division using power series division. My questions are:

- Is power series division a reasonable approach to this problem? I've plotted the power series of $p_{3}$ and compared it to a pointwise estimate of $p_{2} / p_{1}$, it is equivalent on certain intervals, but the power series diverges elsewhere.
- Is it possible to determine $p_3$'s power series' radius and interval of convergence? I believe $e^{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n} / n!$ converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so the power series of $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ should also converge for all $x$.
- Is it possible to determine, or approximate, a Gaussian's central moments using its power series representation?

Comment: Is there a reason to expect there is some nice closed-form formula for $ p_1(x) / p_2(x) $ simpler than the one obtained by directly substituting in the known expressions for $ p_1(x) $ and $ p_2(x) $?

Comment: No, there is no reason to expect a closed-form solution. I would just like to know if my solution is correct, if it converges or if we can do anything useful with it. Alternatively, I'd be interested in any other method of exactly, or approximately, dividing a Gaussian by a GM -- this is the best I could do.

Comment: Maybe I am naive on this topic, but if (to give a silly simple example) you had $ f(x) = e^x $ and $ g(x) = sin(x) $, most people, for most applications, would be content to write $ h(x) = f(x)/g(x) = e^x / sin(x) $, and would view calculating the power series for $ h(x) $ as an entirely unnecessary (and difficult) exercise.

Comment: Sorry, the question is poorly phrased and it does seem to amount to a pointless exercise. I'll try to rephrase the question. The closest I can get to the real question is: In a Bayesian framework (BF), can a GM posterior distribution divided by a GM prior be approximated by a GM? A Gaussian divided by a GM provided by a minimal working example, although I failed to include any of the context in the question, for some reason. I had hoped the power series would allow me to at least approximate the solution's central moments, as a Gaussian divided by GM is usually sufficiently Gaussian (in a BF).